# Why does cooking.sty produce empty output (and overfull hboxes)?

Tags: pdftex, packages, koma-script

For a few years, I've been using the [cooking](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cooking) package to create a nice book with recipes.

Some time ago, the resulting PDF started to be empty, only the TOC is readable, the rest is a white page. What could it be?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cooking}
\pagestyle{recipe}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Salate}
\begin{recipe}{Salade Olivier}

\ingredient{Eine kleine  Zwiebel} \ingredient{fünf größere Essiggurken} und
\ingredient{Kapern} fein Hacken. \ingredient{500g Schinken}
in kleine Quadrate schneiden. \ingredient{Vier Eier} hart
kochen. \ingredient{ca. zehn große Kartoffeln} kochen und pellen. Eier und
Kartoffeln würfeln. Alles zusammen mit \ingredient{einer Dose Erbsen} in eine große Schüssel geben.
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

Just as I wanted to attach the `log` of building `mini.pdf`, I saw that there are massively overfull `hboxes`:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `mini' with ``pdflatex -shell-escape  -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" mini.tex''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 8 language(s) loaded.
(./mini.tex (/home/markus/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2015/04/02 v3.17.2062 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/home/markus/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/home/markus/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/home/markus/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2015/04/02 v3.17.2062 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/home/markus/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/home/markus/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/home/markus/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2015/04/02 v3.17.2062 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cooking/cooking.sty) (./mini.aux)
(./mini.toc)
Overfull \hbox (2481.99472pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--9
[]\OT1/cmr/m/it/12 Salade |

Overfull \hbox (2483.9448pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--9
\OT1/cmr/m/it/12 Olivier  |

Overfull \hbox (2448.99443pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--11
[]|

Overfull \hbox (2448.99443pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--11
|

Overfull \hbox (2448.99443pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--12
[]|

Overfull \hbox (2467.24446pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--12
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 und |

Overfull \hbox (2448.99443pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--12
[]|

Overfull \hbox (2466.33195pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--12
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 fein|

Overfull \hbox (2486.71112pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--12
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 Hacken. |
```

And so on for many lines ...

```
Overfull \hbox (2461.22194pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 15--16
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 sel|

Overfull \hbox (2479.7153pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 15--16
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 geben. |
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] (./mini.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssbx10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti12.pfb>
Output written on mini.pdf (2 pages, 49544 bytes).
Transcript written on mini.log.
```

Can you help me to print my recipes again? All I can offer is the German text of really delicious food ;)

Comment: Your example runs for me, apart from some warnings.

Comment: Does the same happen with `article` instead of `scrartcl`?

Comment: No, with `article` everyting's fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, KOMA-Script adds some more functionality that standard class `article` has.

With an current MiKTeX 2.9 and the current KOMA-Script version `2016/06/14 v3.21` I can compile your given code with only one, IMHO very clear warning:

```
Class scrartcl Warning: incompatible usage of \@ssect detected.
(scrartcl)              You've used the KOMA-Script implementation of \@ssect
(scrartcl)              from within a non compatible caller, that does not
(scrartcl)              \scr@s@ct@@nn@m@ locally.
(scrartcl)              This could result in several error messages on input line 11.
```

Your used version of KOMA-Script seems to be outdated: your log file tells us: `2015/04/02 v3.17.2062`

It seems (I can not test it, I have not that old version of KOMA-Script) that that old KOMA-Script and package `cooking` have a problem to work together.

Please update your system to get the current KOMA-Script.

Please add `\listfiles` as first command of your TeX code, compile three times and compare the resulting list of used packages including version numbers (sic!) with my list:

```
 *File List*
scrartcl.cls    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (type area)
 cooking.sty    1999/06/24 v0.9b Cooking recipes
 ***********
```

I'm sure you will see the differences at once.

Btw that is the resulting pdf on my computer:

[image]